#  Easiest way to dynamically change CSS min-height values?

Tags: css

I am sure what I need is possible but I hope somebody got any advice on what is the best way to achieve it.

I have a div, that will contain text. I want the min-height of the div set to 250px - so that the initial div height is set.

My question is:

If the currently set `min-height: 250px;` gets exceeded by its content, can I apply a new min-height value of 500px as soon as the 250px is passed (e.g if div is forced to a 252px height it automatically sets `min-height: 500px;`)?

Comment: So, basically, do you want `div` to extend its height gradually by 250px?

Comment: It's not possible only with CSS you need to use jQuery for this. Do you want to use jQuery?

Comment: You don't *need* to use jQuery for this, and if jQuery isn't present in the project why introduce it for something this simple?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies, I am using jquery for other things and so can tap in to that but if I can do it with less code and not using Jquery then even better.

Comment: Keaukraine, I am actually looking for it to jump to 500px straight after 250px exceed rather than it gradually increasing. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with plain CSS, but the affect could be achieved using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.height()>parseInt($this.css("min-height"))){
          $this.css("min-height", "500px");
        }
    });
});​
```

[**See Demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/6shWQ/7/) (Demo uses `25px` as initial min-height)

Comment: Curt, thanks for your reply. That works just as I had hoped. Thanks for your help.